# How to solve $D=\sqrt{X^2+MX^2}$ for $X$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How I to solve $D=\sqrt{X^2+MX^2}$ for $X$?

With my rudimentary experience, I find myself incapable. I  apologize for asking a question after asking a similar one previously (several days prior), but the first equation was incorrect, and I have replaced it with the much simpler consecutive. Despite its simplicity, I have been unable to solve it using the strategy of the first equation. I once again impress that I am only an Algebra I student, and so I am unfamiliar with complex terminology, and that this is not a homework problem, but a personal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
D^2 = X^2 + MX^2 \implies (I+M)X^2 = D^2
$$
Solve this for $X$